Issue on Play Store Instant App 'Try Now' button dissapear
I have an existing base app published in both Production and Internal Testing, currently at version code 100 (1.2.0). I then created a separate project for my instant app since its features are different from the base app. The instant app version code is 60 (1.2.0).
Before publishing, I tested the instant app by running it as 'Deploy as Instant' in Android Studio, and it worked perfectly. The final app bundle size is around 19 MB, resulting in this size.
App Size Report
as for my instant app manifest:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:targetSandboxVersion="2"
    tools:targetApi="o">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" dist:title="Instant">
        <dist:delivery>
            <dist:install-time />
        </dist:delivery>
    </dist:module>
    . . . 
</manifest>


and as my build gradle i have installed the required libs
dependencies {
    . . .
    // instant app
    implementation(libs.instant.app)
}

libs.versions.toml:
[versions]
instant-app = "17.0.0"

[libraries]
instant-app = { group = "com.google.android.gms", name = "play-services-instantapps", version.ref = "instant-app" }

To summarize what I have done:

Installed the required libraries for the instant app.
Updated my AndroidManifest file.
Reduced the app size to below 15 MB.
Ensured the applicationId, namespace, and package ID are the same as in my base app.

But the problem is that the 'Try Now' button is not shown on the app page in the Play Store.
I have tried clearing the data and cache of the Play Store. On the first attempt to open the app page, the 'Try Now' button appears, but if the user goes back and reopens the app page, it disappears.
But if I try to open the instant app using an app link, it triggers and opens my instant app.
Is anyone else facing this issue?
